# Auto Color Google Calendar event title based on second last character

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to auto color events based on the second last character in the title, current function has the ability to do so with the last character as endsWith has been employed, but is there a way to change that so it reads the second last character and not the last.

```
function ColorEvents() {

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("ID@group.calendar.google.com")
  var beginDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1); 
  var endDate = new Date(2080, 10, 1);
  Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + calendar.length);

    var events = calendar.getEvents(beginDate, endDate);
    for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
      var e = events[j];
      var title = e.getTitle();
      if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("a")) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the second last character of the string value using Google Apps Script.

In order to check the second last character, when you want to use `endsWith`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("a")) {
```

#### To:

```
if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {
```

- In this sample script,  is used as the search character from your script.

#### Testing:

```js
const search = "";
const str = ["abde", "abce", "abcd"];
const res = str.map(s => s.endsWith(search, s.length - 1));
console.log(res)  // <--- [ false, true, false ]
```

#### Reference:

- [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

### Added:

As other method, the string value including the unicode string is splitted with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and compare it.

#### Modified script:

#### From:

```
if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("a")) {
```

#### To:

```
var search = "";
var ar = [...title.toLowerCase()];  // In your case, I'm not sure whether "toLowerCase()" is required.
if (ar[ar.length - 2] == search) {
```

- In this sample script,  is used as the search character from your script.

#### Testing:

```js
const search = "";
const str = ["abde", "abce", "abcd"];
const res = str.map(s => {
  const ar = [...s];
  return ar[ar.length - 2] == search;
});
console.log(res)  // <--- [ false, true, false ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I have multiple conditions like below:

`if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
      }
      if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.YELLOW);
      }`
As per the modified script, will I have to create a search variable for each condition? 
This didn't work for me: 
`if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {`
Could I be doing something wrong?  
Thank you !!!

Comment: @Rahi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Before your new question, can I ask you about the detail of `This didn't work for me:`? Because in order to answer to `Could I be doing something wrong?`, it is required to know the detail of your current issue. At first, I would like to resolve your current issue. And I had added one more sample script. Can I ask you about the result of it? When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: I am so sorry, what I meant was that this modification didn't work:  
`if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {`

Comment: @Rahi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `this modification didn't work: if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {`. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the sample value of `title` for replicating your issue? By the way, in your question, I understood that you want to search `` at the 2nd last character in `title`. Is my understanding correct? And I had added one more sample script. Can I ask you about the result of it?

Comment: for example the event title is Test event 1

`function ColorEvents() {

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("ID@group.calendar.google.com")
  var beginDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1); 
  var endDate = new Date(2080, 10, 1);

    var events = calendar.getEvents(beginDate, endDate);
    for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
      var e = events[j];
      var title = e.getTitle();
        if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length-1)) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.MAUVE);
      }
    }`

Comment: @Rahi Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. In your sample value of `title` is `test event@`. Is my understanding correct? And  I had added one more sample script. Can I ask you about the result of it?

Comment: I am not sure how to use second script, but lemme try, I am guessing I just add the script where all the `var` values are

Comment: @Rahi Thank you for replying. I could understand about `I am not sure how to use second script`. I deeply apologize about it. And in your sample value of title is `test event@`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The second script worked, but what if I wish to use multiple conditions like MAUVE for ,  RED for ,  YELLOW for 

Comment: basically I am trying to color based on these types of symbols  or  or which will be the second last character of the google calendar event title

Comment: @Rahi Thank you for replying and testing the 2nd proposal. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that in this case, the reason of this issue is due to that 2 bytes characters are included. It seems that `endsWith` can be used for `abce`. On the other hand, when the spread syntax is used, each character can be splitted. So I added it as 2nd proposal.

Comment: you answered my question - I can use multiple conditions with the if statement. the modified script did not have [ ] brackets which is why it wasn't working... but I updated the first script you provided `if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", title.length - 1)) {` to                      `if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", [title.length - 1])) {` and it's working with multiple statements now

Comment: @Rahi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

the working code looks like this, thanks a lot @Tanaike

```
function ColorEvents() {

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("ID@group.calendar.google.com")
  var beginDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1); 
  var endDate = new Date(2080, 10, 1);
  Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + calendar.length);

    var events = calendar.getEvents(beginDate, endDate);
    for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
      var e = events[j];
      var title = e.getTitle();

      if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", [title.length-2])) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED);
      }
      if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", [title.length-2])) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.YELLOW);
      }
      if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", [title.length-2])) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);
      }
        if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("", [title.length-2])) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.MAUVE);
      }
      if (title.toLowerCase().endsWith("️", [title.length-2])) {
        e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.BLUE);
      }
    }
  }
```